# How to extract data from a list in PYTHON

Tags: python

Suppose I have data as follows:

```
A = [{'X1': val1, 'X2': 'val2', 'X3': 'val3', 'X4': val4}]
```

How do I extract val1, val2, val3, val4?

What is quickest way of doing this?

Comment: That looks like JSON data. Is it?

Comment: I think you mean dict({'X1': val1, 'X2': 'val2', 'X3': 'val3', 'X4': val4}) Read this. http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> A = [{'X1': val1, 'X2': 'val2', 'X3': 'val3', 'X4': val4}]
>>> list(A[0].values())
[val1,'val2','val3',val4]
```

Comment: How can it be that val1 and val4 have no quotes in the output? :)

Comment: @IgorChubin I just assumed that user has declared `val1` and `val4` somewhere in his program. :)

Comment: I think that your answer is the best. I will vote for it

Comment: `val1` and `val4` wouldn't appear in the resulting list. If they were defined before `A` was defined, their values would appear in the list. If not, the assignment to `A` would result in a `NameError`. The answer is correct, just not the (faked) output.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure why you need it, but:

```
A[0].values()
```

Will extract val1, val2, val3, val4 into a list.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, extract?

You can extract these data so:

```
A[0].values()
```

They are now extracted :)

Comment: I just tried this and it errors: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'vals'`

Comment: Sorry I have mistyped, values() of course.

Comment: And that was a method from dictionary :) I have mistyped twice :)